# Stop non-English documentation returns from `mthelp`?

Tags: pdf, miktex, viewers

How do I stop non-English documentation returns from `mthelp`? `mthelp graphicx` returns a Polish manual. `mthelp amsldoc` returns an Italian manual. How do I stop this? How do I get a hold of the English manuals (whether in `.html`, `.pdf`, or whatever)?

By the way, I'm running MikTeX 2.8 on a Vista32

UPDATE1: I was able to find the English amsmath documentation on my hard drive at `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\doc\latex\ams\math\amsldoc.pdf`. So, I know it's there. I just don't know how to get `mthelp` to return the right documentation.

I recall installing MikTeX and saying "yes" to some option to include all language specifications. I'm thinking, now, that this was a mistake.

UPDATE2: `mthelp lshort` returns a Russian document :(

Comment: Hi brianjd, you can and should use backticks ('`\``') for paths. Then you also don't need to escape the backslashes.

Comment: See now answers to [How to force MikTeX' texdoc to open package manuals with a PDF reader rather than the DVI viewer?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54474/9237).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting side effect of a complete miktex installation and another argument for a basic installation with following on-the-fly installation of missing packages.

As far as I can see the only way to solve the problem is to deinstall some package with the package manager: The russian lshort is in lshort-russian, the italian amsldoc in italian-doc, and the polish graphics is probably the graphics.html in polish-doc.

Comment: thank you. I uninstalled `italian-doc`. A later call to `mthelp amsldoc` returned and displayed the desired English file --- even though `mthelp --list-only amsldoc` seemed to not know about it back when `italian-doc` was still installed.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the solution you're looking for, but `mthelp --list-only graphicx` will open a browser window, showing an HTML listing of all versions of documentations (including example code etc if any) of `graphicx`. You can then click on the specific file you want to open.

Comment: thanks for the reply. This command is very useful. **However** the way it works for me isn't quite the same as you described. `mthelp --list-only graphicx` returns the list of documentation in the command window but does not open a browser window showing the HTML listing as you described. That's Ok. I can just scroll to the file of interest and then navigate to the file on my hard drive on my own. Would certainly be nicer if it open a browser though!

Comment: There's another little problem with this approach. As mentioned above with `mthelp --list-only graphicx` I can at least see the desired English manual printed in the console and then navigate to it on my hard drive. **However**, `mthelp --list-only amsldoc` **only** prints the location of the Italian version. It never prints the location of the desired English version, which is located at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\2.8\doc\latex\ams\math\amsldoc.pdf. Frustrating. I wonder how many other packages are like this :(

Comment: `mthelp --list-only` will list the files in the command window. `mthelp` will open a browser window if the package documentation contains more than one file (example: hyperref), if there is only one file it will open it directly. `mthelp --view` opens the "main" file. But this applies only to the files belonging together to one package. If a name matches more than one package (e.g. if you have local and a global version of hyperref) mthelp will consider only the first package it finds. That was a problem when a lot packages called their docu "guide", but today there are only few cases left.

Comment: @brianjd Hmm browser windows opened for me; but that was an older version of MikTeX, and I haven't been using MikTeX on a windows box recently, so I'm sorry I didn't give the most recent info. ;-)